# React Refresh Page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, navigation, browser-history

I am making the function to update some information in my database with react as the frontend. The problem is that after i update the item in database i want it to be the realtime but every time i make a new update i have to again refresh the page.
My code looks like this.

```
edit = async (id, quantity, action) => {
    if (action === "inc") {
      await this.props.updateItem(id, quantity + 1);
    }
    if (action === "dec") {
      await this.props.updateItem(id, quantity - 1);
    }
    history.push("/");
    history.push("/cart");
  };
```

This is the function i use to update the item.
Please help, Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's a problem? Update your items after BE call finished with state updating or redux store updates.

Comment: I dont want to add last to history.push() lines in my code. Moreover, my data is coming from redux only at initial request.

Answer (score 0):

Check this documentation

> https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#adding-local-state-to-a-class

Please create a constructor for the React component, like below

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {item: {id: 1, 'quantity': 0}; // 0 is default value.
  }
```

After every `edit` of quantity, please update the state to a new value

```
this.setState({'id': 1, quantity:  this.state.quantity + 1});
```

Now, use the state to render the HTML

```
render() {
    return (<div>
        <h1>Item ID: {this.state.id}</h1>
        <h2>Item Count: {this.state.quantity}</h2>
    </div>)
}
```